# How to bring specific curves in-front in ZedGraph

Tags: c#, plot, zedgraph, curves

I have two curves on the zedgraph control, after plotting both the curves...

```
PointPairList thresholdList = new PointPairList();
PointPairList powerList = new PointPairList();

private void plotPower()
{
        // Create an object to access ZedGraph Pane
        GraphPane pane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;            
        LineItem thresholdLine = new LineItem("thresholdLine");
        LineItem powerLine = new LineItem("powerLine");

        // Set the Threshold Limit
        double thresoldLimit = Convert.ToDouble(numAnalysisThreshold2.Value);

        // Points
        double[] x = new double[]{0, pane.XAxis.Scale.Max};
        double[] y = new double[]{thresoldLimit, thresoldLimit};

        // Set the threshold line curve list
        thresholdList.Add(x, y); 

        // Set the Power Line curve list
        powerdList.Add(XData, YData);

        // Add Curves
        thresholdLine = pane.AddCurve("", thresholdList, Color.Red, SymbolType.None);
        powerLine = pane.AddCurve("", powerList, Color.Red, SymbolType.None);

        // Refresh Chart
        this.Invalidate();
        zedGraphControl1.Refresh();
}
```

from the above code, I managed to plot the two curves as power line curve over the threshold line curve.

Now my questions is, if I want to bring any one of the curve in front....Is there any method available(ex: bringittoFront()....)...?

Thanks a lot for your time ....:)

Comment: Very though issue, assuming that a CurveItem can be used on *several* GraphPanes...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [GraphPane](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/T_ZedGraph_GraphPane.htm) contains a [CurveList](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/P_ZedGraph_GraphPane_CurveList.htm) property, and the [CurveList](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/T_ZedGraph_CurveList.htm) class is a subclass of `List<CurveItem>`. If you set the [CurveItem.Tag](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/F_ZedGraph_CurveItem_Tag.htm) property for each curve that you draw, I believe you should be able to sort the curve items by using the `CurveList.Sort(IComparer<CurveItem>)` method and using the `Tag` to represent the sorting order.

**UPDATE JUNE 19**

Simple example: two lines, the blue `line2` with `line2.Tag = 2` and the red `line1` with `line1.Tag = 1`. In the initialization `line2` is added first to the graph pane, so it will be displayed on top.

```
void GraphInit()
{
    var line2 = _graph.GraphPane.AddCurve("Second", 
        new[] { 0.1, 0.5, 0.9 }, new[] { 0.1, 0.5, 0.1 }, Color.Blue);
    line2.Tag = 2;

    var line1 = _graph.GraphPane.AddCurve("First", 
        new[] { 0.1, 0.5, 0.9 }, new[] { 0.1, 0.5, 0.9 }, Color.Red);
    line1.Tag = 1;

    _graph.Refresh();
}
```

[image: Initial display before sorting]

To sort, first implement a class that implements `IComparer<CurveItem>`, and that sorts the curve items in ascending order based on the numerical value of the `CurveItem` `Tag` property:

```
class CurveItemTagComparer : IComparer<CurveItem>
{
    public int Compare(CurveItem x, CurveItem y)
    {
        return ((int)x.Tag).CompareTo((int)y.Tag);
    }
}
```

To perform re-sorting and update the graph, implement the following event handler for the *Sort* button:

```
void SortButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _graph.GraphPane.CurveList.Sort(new CurveItemTagComparer());
    _graph.Refresh();
}
```

Now, when clicking the *Sort* button, the curves will be sorted such that the curve with the lowest tag value, i.e. `line1`, will instead be drawn on top. Additionally, note that the curve order in the legend is changed along.

[image: Graph after Sort button is clicked]

Comment: wow, you just made my day.... I struggled a lot to set the tag property of the curve....You're the * & Thanks a million for the clear explanation...:)

Comment: This gives me a compile error on the `_graph.GraphPane.CurveList.Sort()` line - "No overload for method 'Sort' takes 1 arguments" - The params seem to be `Sort(SortType type, int index)`.

Answer (score 7):

There is a very easy way. Use the [`Move()`](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/M_ZedGraph_CurveList_Move.htm%20%22Move%28%29) method in the `CurveList` class. For example in:

`zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.CurveList.Move(index,relativePos)`

setting `relativePos` to `-1` will move the object one position earlier in the list, while `1` will move it one position later. To move an item to the beginning of the list, use a large negative value (such as `-999`). To move it to the end of the list, use a large positive value.

Answer (score 4):

And, for who needs it, this is the code for the IComparer class for vb.net:

```
    Public Class CurveItemTagComparer
    Implements IComparer(Of CurveItem)
    Function Compare(ByVal x As ZedGraph.CurveItem, ByVal y As ZedGraph.CurveItem) As Integer _
    Implements System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of CurveItem).Compare
        Return CInt(x.Tag).CompareTo(CInt(y.Tag))
    End Function
End Class
```

Giovanni